# Parse string into multidimensional array with single regex?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if anyone here could help me. I have the following string:

```
$str = 'unit1(field1,field2,field3),unit2(field4,field5,field6)';
```

I am trying to parse this string to create the following array:

```
array(
  'unit1' => array('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
  'unit2' => array('field4', 'field5', 'field6')
)
```

I am pretty hopeless with regex so I am not even sure where to start with this.

Thanks

Comment: I think you're missing some single quotes in the bottom `unit2`?

Comment: To learn about regex you can start here http://www.regular-expressions.info/. Then check out `preg_match` and `preg_match_all` on the PHP docs. Once you read all that try to build your own solution and come back with the code that failed and somebody might help.

Comment: Your first code example isn't a string.

Comment: why not choose a more standardized format like JSON: `[{"unit":"unit1", "fields":["field1","field2"]},...]` and `json_decode($str)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without using regular expressions

```
 $str = 'unit1(field1,field2,field3),unit2(field4,field5,field6)';
 $str = trim($str, ")");
 $parts = explode("),",$str);
 $results = array();
 foreach($parts as $part){
      list($key, $value) = explode("(", $part,2);
      $results[$key] = explode(",", $value);
 }
```

Now the $results will contain your output as you specified.